# Правильный запрос к смежным таблицам mysql php

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть 3 таблицы.
Users (клиенты), company (компании), users to company (смежная таблица)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно сформировать запрос сразу к трем таблицам?
Нам нужно получить информацию что Андрей относится к компании Google, а Виталий к компании Yandex.

```
<?php
  $host = 'localhost';
  $user = '*';
  $db_name = '*';
  $pass = '*';
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
  $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<span>".$row['name']."</span><span>".$row['title']."</span>";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT u.name, c.title
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_to_company on u.id = user_to_company.id_user
INNER JOIN company с on c.id = user_to_company.id_company`

Comment: а в echo какие переменные выводить? что за u.name?

Comment: как выводить я не знаю вопрос был как правильно сформировать запрос сразу к трем таблицам

Comment: Что тогда за u.name? Вы либо распишите полностью либо не пишите вообще...

Comment: u это псевдоним для таблиц user чтобы 2 и более раз не писать user, объявляется здесь FROM users u